# @Access ignored by EclipseLink, works ok in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have an Entity with `@EmbeddedId` on a Field, and I overrode the access type for a field making it `Property` access. But this is ignored by `EclipseLink`, in `Hibernate` it's ok. Also Netbeans shows me error because of this:

**The class must use a consistent access type (either field or property).

There is no ID defined for this entity hierarchy.**

```
@EmbeddedId
private OneId id;

@Transient
private String cosmin;

@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) // ??
public String getCosmin() {
    return cosmin;
}

public void setCosmin(String cosmin) {
    this.cosmin = cosmin;
}
```

Comment: Have your tried to annotate the class with `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)`?

Comment: yeah :) no good, tried to remove EmbeddedId and put a regular Id. No good.

Comment: Try marking your class with @Access(AccessType.FIELD) annotation?

Comment: What version are you using?  Access on a property is part of JPA 2.0 EL >= 2.0

Answer (score 5):

Problem is that entity misses following class level annotation:

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
```

Just add it the next from @Entity. When both fields and methods are annotated, you do not know which access type is actually used. In your case it seems to be method access, and @EmbeddedId is simply ignored.

In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> The behavior of applications that mix the placement of annotations on
>   fields and properties within an entity hierarchy without explicitly
>   specifying the Access annotation is undefined.
>   ...
>   When Access(FIELD) is applied to such a class, it is possible to
>   selectively designate individual attributes within the class for
>   property access. To specify a persistent property for access by the
>   persistence provider runtime, that property must be designated
>   Access(PROPERTY).

.